# Kinect Body Color

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I am writing an application that requires the background removal(where the player is), and masking the user body with some color or any character(like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599658/how-to-create-kinect-avatar).
Thanks in advance

Comment: i totally don't get what do you need

Comment: See http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Display-Kinect-color-image-containing-only-players-aka-background-removal and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599658/how-to-create-kinect-avatar/10600919#10600919

Comment: @ravithejag: People are downvoting you because you haven't asked a question.  What's the problem?  What's the issue?  What are you trying to do with it?  What have you tried?  What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial at [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Display-Kinect-color-image-containing-only-players-aka-background-removal), even though is in the old beta 2, is easy to convert. Here is final code(converted)

```
    public static class KinectExtensions
    {
        public static WriteableBitmap CreateLivePlayerRenderer(this KinectSensor sensor)
        {
            if (sensor.DepthStream.FrameWidth == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Either open the depth stream before calling this method or use the overload which takes in the resolution that the depth stream will later be opened with.");
            return CreateLivePlayerRenderer(sensor, sensor.DepthStream.FrameWidth, sensor.DepthStream.FrameHeight);
        }

        public static WriteableBitmap CreateLivePlayerRenderer(this KinectSensor sensor, int depthWidth, int depthHeight)
        {
            AllFramesReadyEventArgs d = new AllFramesReadyEventArgs();
            using (DepthImageFrame depthImage = d.OpenDepthImageFrame())
            {
                WriteableBitmap target = new WriteableBitmap(depthWidth, depthHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);
                var depthRect = new System.Windows.Int32Rect(0, 0, depthWidth, depthHeight);

                sensor.DepthFrameReady += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Debug.Assert(depthImage.Height == depthHeight && depthImage.Width == depthWidth);
                };

                sensor.ColorFrameReady += (s, e) =>
                {
                    // don't do anything if we don't yet have a depth image
                    DepthImageFrame colorImage = depthImage;
                    if (colorImage.BytesPerPixel == null) return;

                    byte[] color = new byte[sensor.ColorStream.FramePixelDataLength];
                    e.OpenColorImageFrame().CopyPixelDataTo(color);

                    byte[] output = new byte[depthWidth * depthHeight * 4];

                    // loop over each pixel in the depth image
                    int outputIndex = 0;
                    for (int depthY = 0, depthIndex = 0; depthY < depthHeight; depthY++)
                    {
                        for (int depthX = 0; depthX < depthWidth; depthX++, depthIndex += 2)
                        {
                            short[] bits = new short[colorImage.BytesPerPixel];
                            depthImage.CopyPixelDataTo(bits);
                            // combine the 2 bytes of depth data representing this pixel
                            short depthValue = (short)(bits[depthIndex] | (bits[depthIndex + 1] << 8));

                            // extract the id of a tracked player from the first bit of depth data for this pixel
                            int player = bits[depthIndex] & 7;

                            // find a pixel in the color image which matches this coordinate from the depth image
                            int colorX, colorY;
                            ColorImagePoint colorPoint = depthImage.MapToColorImagePoint(depthImage.Width, depthImage.Height, sensor.ColorStream.Format);


                            // ensure that the calculated color location is within the bounds of the image
                            colorX = colorPoint.X;
                            colorY = colorPoint.Y;

                            output[outputIndex++] = color[(4 * (colorX + (colorY * e.OpenColorImageFrame().Width))) + 0];
                            output[outputIndex++] = color[(4 * (colorX + (colorY * e.OpenColorImageFrame().Width))) + 1];
                            output[outputIndex++] = color[(4 * (colorX + (colorY * e.OpenColorImageFrame().Width))) + 2];
                            output[outputIndex++] = player > 0 ? (byte)255 : (byte)0;
                        }
                    }
                    target.WritePixels(depthRect, output, depthWidth * PixelFormats.Bgra32.BitsPerPixel / 8, 0);
                };
                return target;
            }
        }
    }
```

And my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599658/how-to-create-kinect-avatar/10600919#10600919 explains how to create the character. Good Luck! Hope this Helps!